# ABCDE is a regular pentagon, find angle CFD considering figure provided

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> As for the picture below, in which ABCDE is a regular 
>   pentagon, find angle CFD. (List of problems for math olympics preparation)

[image]

Attempt: As ABCDE is a regular pentagon, all sides are equal and internal angles for the pentagon are $108^\circ$. So the angles FED and CBF are $84^\circ$. And angle BFE is $156^\circ$. But not seeing how to find a way to compute CFD.

Hints and solutions welcomed. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: WLOG, Let the length of one side of the regular pentagon be 1. Draw a straight line from B to E and label the midpoint of BE as the point G. Let point H be the midpoint of CD. Draw the straight line HGF and find the length of HF = HG + GF. Then use trig on FHD to find angle CFD= 2 x (angle HFD)